# Actionbar does not change title in backstack

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, fragment, title

I have a problem: backstack does not return title in action bar.

I have this (working) code fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(
    LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_products_layout,container,false);

   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).restoreActionBar(getString(R.string.title_list_products));

    return rootview;
}
```

But when I want to create Menu in ActionBar, I must call `SetHasOptionsMenu(true)` in  `onCreateView` (above).

After, menu works but backstack does not change title when I BackPressed